# Dev C++ couldn't support with iostream.h header file in C++

Tags: c++, iostream, dev-c++

Why the "Dev C++" couldn't support with iostream.h header file in C++..? How can I include iostream.h header file in Dev C++?

Comment: `iostream.h` isn't a standard C++ header.

Comment: If you are using a compiler that is not pre-historic, then you need to `#include <iostream>`, which is a standard C++ header.

Comment: http://members.gamedev.net/sicrane/articles/iostream.html gives a rather ok explanation.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First of all, Dev C is not a compiler, it's an IDE that interfaces with a compiler (most presumably GCC/MingW in your case). The compiler suite is the one having the header files, not the IDE.

Just do

```
#include <iostream>
```

instead of

```
#include <iostream.h>
```

and also add `using namespace std;` to execute `cout` and `cin` in Dev C program.

Answer (score 5):

`<iostream.h>` is not a standard header file (if anything supports it, it's for backward compatibility from long ago). Use `<iostream>` instead. None of the header files introduced in C++ have an extension. The same advice goes for `<fstream>` over `<fstream.h>` as well.

Answer (score 1):

try  to include this way.

```
      #include<iostream>
```

Comment: Yeah... yeah... The thing is.... I often compare C++ with "C"... #include <iostream> is a way to include it. Thanks Guys..! :)